# Return Laravel options() as array when no optional parameter has been provided

Tags: laravel

Laravel has the super handy [optional()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-optional) helper.

I would like to combine it with a custom Model attribute like this:

```
// this method is on the User model
public function getDataAttribute()
{
    // this data comes from another service
    $data = [
        'one' => 1,
        'two' => 2,
    ];

    return optional($data);
}
```

So I can use it like this:

```
$user->data->one // 1
$user->data->two // 2
$user->data->three // null
```

However, I am also trying to return the entire array by doing:

```
dump($user->data); // this should dump the internal $data array
```

But this will return an instance of Illuminate\Support\Optional with a `value` property.

```
Illuminate\Support\Optional {#1416 ▼
  #value: {#2410 ▼
    +"one": 1
    +"two": 2
  }
}
```

Is it possible to return the original $data array if no "sub"parameter (= a child attribute of $user->data) is given? Or is there a possibility to detect a child parameter in the getDataAttribute()?

I hope it's clear what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: what is a "sub" parameter ?

Comment: @lagbox The child attribute of $user->data, so for example $user->data->one. Whenever I do $user->data->xxx the xxx will be resolved through the optional() helper getter. But I want optional() to return the whole array in case no "sub" parameter is called, like so: $user->data

Comment: you can't do what you want with PHP but you could macro a method to the `Optional` class that would return the "value" (underlying object) if you wanted to ... sidenote you would have to use array notation when dealing with the optional object if you wanted to access the elements of an underlying array instead of an object

Comment: `optional` method treats the argument as an object, that's why it returns as an object. read this line from docs description `allows you to access properties or call methods on that object.`

Comment: @lagbox using a macro would mean that I would have to access the underlying value by $user->data->all(), for example correct? maybe I could even cast the value to an array in that case...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [lagbox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2109233/lagbox) for pushing me in the right direction. I have solved this by using the following macro:

```
Illuminate\Support\Optional::macro('toArray', function()
{
    return (array) $this->value;
});
```

This way I can access all data by using:

```
$user->data->toArray();
```

Comment: Not sure how that solves any problem described in the question. You could have just done `(array) $user->data` instead of that.

Comment: @miken32 because they want what is held inside the `Optional` and `$value` is protected ... go make an `Optional` object and cast it to an array and see what happens

Comment: Ah, makes sense; I didn't realize it was a protected property.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for cannot be achieved.

My suggestion would be to keep things simple and define a `getter` method and pass the key of the array you want and from there return your data respectively, e.g.:

```
public function getData($key = null) {
    $data = [
        'one' => 1,
        'two' => 2,
    ];

    if (!$key) {
        return $data;
    }

    return $data[$key] ?? null;
}
```

Notice also how this method is no longer an attribute, this is because AFAIR, you cannot pass args to attribute methods.

**Reading Material**

[Null coalescing operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op)

Comment: Thanks, this would have actually been my alternative solution. I was just hoping I could achieve what I wanted to with the original idea.